# dynamic global value replacement in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var str="Welcome to Microsoft! ";
var val="Microsoft!";

document.write(str.replace('/'+val'+/gi', "W3Schools"));

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

this is not working, how to use val dynamically ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-pass-a-variable-to-a-regular-expression-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot construct a *regex literal* trough string concatenation

try:

```
var str="Welcome to Microsoft! ";
var val="Microsoft!";

document.write(str.replace(new RegExp(val, 'gi'), "http://www.w3fools.com"));
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the argument for replace() a regular expression. If you put it in quotes, it is simply a string. Use the RegExp constructor instead:

```
document.write(str.replace(new RegExp(val, 'gi'), "W3Schools"));
```